# Selenium in Python: Breaking a While Loop After an Onclick Attribute Changes

Tags: python, selenium

I'm looking for a way to stop a loop that continues to click a "Next Page" button until it is no longer clickable on a web-based system, which is only indicated by a change of the Onclick value from:

```
onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('m$main$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl02$ctl20','')"
```

to

```
onclick="return false;__doPostBack('m$main$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl02$ctl20','')"
```

My problem is that I currently don't have a way to get Selenium to recognize that this change has been made.

As of now, I've been able to write something like this:

```
while (driver.find_element_by_class_name('rgPageNext').is_enabled()) is True:
    time.sleep(1)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('rgPageNext').click()
```

However, the button is always enabled even though the button doesn't do anything after it reaches the last page, which results in Selenium continually trying to click the button.

The complete info from inspecting the element of the button is as follows:

```
<input type="button" name="m$main$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl02$ctl20" value=" " onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('m$main$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl02$ctl20','')" title="Next Page" class="rgPageNext">

<input type="button" name="m$main$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl02$ctl20" value=" " onclick="return false;__doPostBack('m$main$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl02$ctl20','')" title="Next Page" class="rgPageNext">
```

Comment: Maybe you can try change the while loop condition to - `while not driver.find_element_by_class_name('rgPageNext').get_attribute('onclick').startswith("return false;"):`

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Ok, sure I will post it as a answer, just incase anyone else also comes accross similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try checking the `'onclick'` attribute, whether its string startswith `return false;` , if so you should end the loop at the time. For that, change the while loop condition to -

```
while not driver.find_element_by_class_name('rgPageNext').get_attribute('onclick').startsw‌​ith("return false;"):
```